# Is there an explanation why my OpenCV code in Python will read some mp4/avi files and others not?

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I am working with basic code to read video into a variable.
The `cv2.VideoCapture()` function sometimes takes the video then and sometimes not. I have also tried to make a video over phone and/or webcam to implement this, but still didnt work.
However, for a video which is from a tutorial, this works totally fine.

My test Video, which worked: https://ufile.io/vk9sdy27

My test Video, which did not work: https://ufile.io/y1uyw8lv

So my question here is why do some videos work and some do not? I actually would like to film some on my own and analyze them then.

I already went through most `cv2.VideoCapture()` posts on the internet (as far as I could find them). All of them however did not answer my question, but were related to somehow similar but different topics.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pandas as pd #not necessary for this part of the code
from datetime import datetime #not necessary for this part of the code

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("60 BPM Metronome.mp4")
frames_count, fps, width, height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT), 
cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS), cap.get(
    cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
width = int(width)
height = int(height)
print(frames_count, fps, width, height)
```

I should get the frames_count, fps, width and height. They are crucial for the rest of the my code.

Thanks for any help in advance already.

Comment: What do you mean: "sometimes takes the video then and sometimes not." ?

Comment: both files works for me on Linux Mint. But your file has name `60-bpm-metronome.mp4`, not `60 BPM Metronome.mp4`. Maybe you have wrong name in code. As I know OpenCV mostly doesn't raise exception when file/stream is wrong but it gives wrong values on `None`

Comment: unfortunately that is not the problem, but when you say it is working on your machine, I will also try on another PC to confirm - just didnt have the time to check it yet
and thanks for the replys already!